# Why doesn't show mongofiles my files?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I have a MongoDB, with a password protected database 'files_db' on a 2 server replica set. When I login directly, using commandline options to give username / password it works, and I see the GridFS collection 'documents' (nonstandard name) with quite a lot of files. When I try to access them using Mongofiles however, I don't seem to get access to the files:

```
[username@mongoserver ~]$ mongo 1.2.3.4/files_db -u username -p 'password'
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: 1.2.3.4/files_db
> db.documents.files.count()
392743
> exit
bye
[username@mongoserver ~]$mongofiles -vvv --host 1.2.3.4 -d 'files_db' -c 'documents' -u username -p 'password' list
Fri Jul 1 4:55:43 creating new connection to:1.2.3.4:27017
Fri Jul 1 4:55:43 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Fri Jul 1 4:55:43 connected connection!
connected to: 1.2.3.4
[username@mongoserver ~]$
```

I don't understand why. At first I had password issue, the user/pass was in another database, so I fixed that. It could be replica set related? I am sure I'm on the primary. I just want to retreive 2 or 3 files for examination.

Comment: In your shell example you are counting documents in the `files` collection; in your `mongofiles` example you pass `documents` as the collection name.  It looks like you probably want to use `mongofiles -c 'files'...` if you aren't using the default GridFS namespace.

Answer (score 0):

-c is ignored. There's no argument to specify gridfs namespace.

Answer (score 0):

refer [Using mongofiles with GridFS in a meteor app - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172205/using-mongofiles-with-gridfs-in-a-meteor-app), the `collection` option actually is `prefix` -> `mongofiles --help` show this:

```
--prefix=<prefix>     GridFS prefix to use (default is 'fs') (default: fs)
```

and refer [list prefix](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/#commands) :

```
list <prefix>
Lists the files in the GridFS store. The characters specified after list (e.g. <prefix>) optionally limit the list of returned items to files that begin with that string of characters.
```

your command should be:

```
mongofiles -vvv --host 1.2.3.4 -d files_db username -p password list documents
```